# Solving an ode y'=f (x) with numerical values of f (x) but without analitical expresion

Tags: python, ode

I want to solve an ODE numerically in python, like
`y'=f(x)` (with boundary condition `y(0)=0`). I don't know what the analytical expression of function `f(x)`, instead I have a set of points (data) of this function for the domain where I want to solve the differential equation.

I have tried with [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). But this method works when you know the explicit analytical expression for `f(x)`, which is not my case. In particular, I have the following code with the function `f(x)` in an array (**For simplicity I consider a known `f(x)`, but in my real problem this array `f(x)` comes from a numerical simulation without known analytical expression**).

The following code doesn't work, since odeint thinks that I have `y'=x`, and not my values `f(x)`:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def dy_dx(y, f):
    return f #it doesn't work!!


xs = np.linspace(0,10,100)

f = np.sin(xs)*np.exp(-0.1*xs) #data of the function f, but in my real problem I DON'T KNOW THE ANALITICAL SOLUTION! JUST ONLY the points

ys = odeint(dy_dx, 0.0, xs)
```

There must be something in Python that can solve this. Basically you are solving the ode numerically and you know what the values of `f(x)` in the domain of the ode.

Comment: What dimension has `x`? In what form are the values of `f` given? Is the equation for `f` a simultaneous differential equation? If yes, did you try to solve it as a coupled system?

Comment: And yes, the `odeint` function calls `dy_dx` with arguments `(y,t)` and then possibly additional parameters given in the `args=` optional paramter.

Comment: The ode that I say is 1-dimensional y(x), xs is just the array of the domain of my ode y'(x)=f(x), so [0,10]. There is nothing to do here with a coupled system I think. As I say, I only know what are the values of f(x) in the domain [0,10] where I want to solve the ode, but I don't know what is the analitical expresion, since the points f(x) comes from other numerical simulation

Comment: Has the other simulation a dense output option? Else you need to apply interpolation. // If you were to plot `f`, how would you produce the lines?

Comment: Yes, I can do an interpolation from the output f(x). But still, in this case how can I introduce this interpolation in the formalism of odeint?

Comment: Your task is a simple integration, why do you want to use odeint for it? A cumulative quadrature routine does the same with less effort around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this using the quadrature routines of `scipy.integrate`. If you really want to use the complicated form, you have to use interpolation, for instance as in

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0,10,100+1);
fs = np.sin(xs)*np.exp(-0.1*xs) # = Imag( exp((1j-0.1)*x) )
# the exact anti-derivative of f is 
# F = Imag( (exp((1j-0.1)*x)-1)/(1j-0.1) )
#   = Imag( -(1j+0.1)*(exp((1j-0.1)*x)-1)/(1.01) )
#   = 1/1.01 - exp(-0.1*x)/1.01 * ( cos(x) + 0.1*sin(x) )

def IntF(x): return (1-np.exp(-0.1*x)*(np.cos(x)+0.1*np.sin(x)))/1.01 

f = interp1d(xs, fs, kind="quadratic", fill_value="extrapolate")

def dy_dx(y, x):
    return f(x) 

ys = odeint(dy_dx, 0.0, xs)

for x,y in zip(xs, ys): print "%8.4f %20.15f %20.15f"%(x,y,IntF(x))
```

with the first 10 lines

```
    x          interpolated           exact
 --------------------------------------------------
  0.0000    0.000000000000000    0.000000000000000
  0.1000    0.004965420470493    0.004962659238991
  0.2000    0.019671988500299    0.019669801188631
  0.3000    0.043783730081358    0.043781529336000
  0.4000    0.076872788780423    0.076870713937278
  0.5000    0.118430993242631    0.118428986914274
  0.6000    0.167875357240100    0.167873429717074
  0.7000    0.224555718642310    0.224553873611032
  0.8000    0.287762489870417    0.287760727322230
  0.9000    0.356734939606963    0.356733243391002
  1.0000    0.430669760236151    0.430668131955269
```